# How to get all logged in user id in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin and needs to get all user who is currently logged into website. What i'm trying

```
function login($login, $user) {

    //add new option to check whos online
    $users = get_option( 'online-users', array() );

    if ( in_array( $user->ID, $users ) ){
        return;
    }

    $users[] = $user->ID;

    update_option(  'online-users', $users );
}
add_action('wp_login','login', 10, 2);


function logout() {
    $users = get_option( 'online-users', array() );

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    if ( ! in_array( $user_id, $users ) ){
        return;
    }

    update_option( 'online-users', array_diff( $users , array( $user_id ) ) );
}
add_action( 'clear_auth_cookie', 'logout' , 10 );
```

This works fine if user manually logged out, but if user does't manually logged out this logic fails, because wordpress automatically logged out a user after some time of inactivity.

Help me..
Thanks..

Comment: There is http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ subsite for question about wordpress

Answer (score 1):

[Transients](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) could work for you if your WP setup stores them in database. So whenever user logs-in or opens a page, you store a transient with name like 'active_user_[user_id]' and expiry in about 1 minute.

Then wherever you need the count, you just count the transients. This just have two caveats:

1. Transients don't vanish from database unless you query them by `get_transient()`, that's where their expiry is evaluated. So you will probably  need two queries, first one that selects their names from DB, and second a loop that will go through them, call `get_transient()` on each one of them and raise the counter if they return non-false value.
2. This won't work if your transients are stored in Memcached or other in-memory database, because there you have to specify transient keys exactly.. while from MySQL you can query them with wildcards as: `SELECT * FROM $wpdb->options WHERE option_name LIKE '_transient_active_user_%'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid you cannot. To track user activity fine you should write last user actions (i.e. browse pages) into custom user meta (or custom db table).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this WP script for [track online](https://github.com/bordoni/online-now) users. I hope it will work fine for you